# Designing a multi-client server w/ forks

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to design a multi-client server and I also wish to limit the number of users connected. In C-ish pseudocode, my server looks like

```
// binding and listening
bind(...);
listen(...);
while (1) {
   int sockfd = accept(...);
   numConnections++;
   if (numConnections > MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS) {
      numConnections--;
      continue;
   }
   pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0) {
      // do my server stuff
      // stuff...
      // done
      numConnections--;
   } else {
      close(...);
   }
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the fork process; in particular, I'm not sure how to handle the `numConnections` since I can't really decrement it when a child disconnects (the child process opens a copy of the program right?). How should I fix this?

Comment: In any case your parent process must *wait* the children to finish, see `waitpid`. You could use a semaphore to count the number of connections, use `sem_getvalue` to see if there are any usable connections...

Comment: @Antti Haapala, Sems are no good. Each time a process is killed, you'd effectively be lowering the max number of connections by 1.  Your first suggestion (`waitpid`) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Post-fork model**

No worker reuse.

```
sig_child_handler:
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
       --numConnections;

    signal(SIGCHLD, sig_child_handler);

main:
    daemonize();
    signal(...); // Catch signals to forward to children.
    signal(SIGCHLD, sig_child_handler);

    int server_socket = socket(...);
    bind(server_socket, ...);
    listen(server_socket ...);
    while (1) {
       // Wait for a slot to open up.
       // Because we have a SIGCHLD signal handler,
       // sleep() will be interrupted by a child exiting.
       while (numConnections >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS)
          sleep(1);

       // Wait for a connection.
        int client_socket = accept(server_socket, ...);

       // If accept() was interrupted by a child exiting, try again.
       if (sockfd == -1 && errno == EINTR)
          continue;

       ++numConnections;
       pid_t pid = fork();
       if (pid == 0) {
          ...
          exit(0);
       }
    }
```

**Pre-fork model**

Fixed number of reused workers. (Technically, it can be made so that the number of children varies. This would require some IPC.) Multiple children wait on the same server socket, but only one will receive the connection.

```
main:
    daemonize();
    signal(...); // Catch signals to forward to children.

    int server_socket = socket(...);
    bind(server_socket, ...);
    listen(server_socket ...);
    while (1) {
       while (numConnections >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS) {
          if (wait(NULL) > 0)
             --numConnections;
       }

       pid_t pid = fork();
       if (pid == 0) {
          while (1) {
             int client_socket = accept(server_socket, ...);
             ...
          }
       }

       ++numConnections;
    }
```

---

This is the easy part. The hard part is error handling!